# How to encode php oci LOBs to javascript base64 string

Tags: php, oracle, blob, clob

I am trying to run a simple select query against my OracleDB and retrieve my image stored as a LOB. However, all I am getting is this

```
����JFIFHH��XExifMM*�i&�����8Photoshop 3.08BIM8BIM%��ُ�� ���B~��"�� ���}!1AQa"q2���#B��R��$3br� %&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz��������������������������������������������������������������������������� ���w!1AQaq"2�B���� #3R�br� $4�%�&'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz��������������������������������������������������������������������������C ��C  �� ��?��@A��$�v� ����n:�H�# ϼ��'���O���r8�>��ڣ��OS[ϗ!hG�:�j+������ךt�g���ӊ�g���OB9�X�]��� ��}��U|� �x���m�7a�S�cs��Q���܊M����L��P�;�Rq�ta���\֧�U-�B�����+ �r��e!f��w�?
```

I followed [PHP's documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/oci8.examples.php) on fetching CLOB data:

```
// Fetching CLOB data

$query = 'SELECT myclob FROM mytable WHERE mykey = :mykey';

$stid = oci_parse ($conn, $query);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":mykey", $mykey, 5);
oci_execute($stid);

while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_LOBS)) {
    echo $row['MYCLOB'];
    unset($row);  
}
```

My issue is I want the output to be in base64 and not whatever that is... any suggestions or answers would help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully you are storing it as a BLOB, not a CLOB.

To encode the return value use [base64_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php).